# Search father (x) of the number D(x) and measure time and memory consumed

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded, memory-optimization

We define function D(x) as following:

D(x) = x + sum of digits of x
+ sum of prime factors of x   then call x the father of D(x)

Write a program that gets input `t` at the first line and then gets an input in the next `t` lines. If that input had father, print `YES` otherwise `NO`

For example 12 is the father of 20
20 = 12 + (1 + 2) + (2 + 3)

preferably write a separate function for each of these tasks:

1. Getting sum of the digits of a number
2. Getting prime factors of a number
3. Calculating D(x)

**Notice** that if you do lots of operations, you may get time limit error.

**Time limit: 0.5 seconds

Memory limit: 128 MB**

**Input:**
You get an input number `t` at the first line and then in the next `t` lines, you get number `n` for which you should solve the problem
[image]
**Output:**
Print the answer to each input in `t` lines.

**Example:**
Sample input:

> 2
>   4
>   20

Sample output:

> NO
>   YES

I've written the code with python:

```
# function that returns the unique prime factors of number n as a list
def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    factors = list(set(factors))
    return factors


# function that returns the sum of digits of number n
def sum_digits(n):
    r = 0
    while n:
        r, n = r + n % 10, n // 10
    return r


# function to calculate the offspring of number X {D(X)}
def Offspring(X):
    DX = X + sum(prime_factors(X)) + sum_digits(X)
    return DX


ChildFather = {i: Offspring(i) for i in range(4, 1001)}
ChildFatherValues = list(set(list(ChildFather.values())))
ChildFather.clear()
Fathers = [i for i in ChildFatherValues if i <= 1000]
ChildFatherValues.clear()
t = eval(input())
for i in range(0, t):
    n = eval(input())
    if n in Fathers:
        print('YES')
    else:
        print('NO')
```

I guess this part of code

```
ChildFather = {i: Offspring(i) for i in range(4, 1001)}
ChildFatherValues = list(set(list(ChildFather.values())))
ChildFather.clear()
Fathers = [i for i in ChildFatherValues if i <= 1000]
ChildFatherValues.clear()
```

is the bottle-neck for time limit. since I don't know how to find `x` by having `D(x)`, I've solved the problem this way:

```
ChildFather = {i: Offspring(i) for i in range(4, 1001)}
```

for numbers `4<= n<= 1000`, I've created a dictionary {n:D(n)}

```
ChildFatherValues = list(set(list(ChildFather.values())))
ChildFather.clear()
```

created a list of unique values of the dictionary and deallocated the memory used for the dictionary

```
Fathers = [i for i in ChildFatherValues if i <= 1000]
ChildFatherValues.clear()
```

create a list of values smaller than 1000 and deallocated memory used for the original list

```
t = eval(input())
for i in range(0, t):
    n = eval(input())
    if n in Fathers:
        print('YES')
    else:
        print('NO')
```

If a given number exists `n` in the final provided list, I understand that `n` can be written as `D(m)=m+sum of digits of m + sum of prime factors of m` so `n` has the father `m` and I'll print `Yes` otherwise `NO`
But seems that the program is not efficient.

1. How can I measure the time consumed by this python program at run-time?
2. How can I measure the memory consumed by this python program at run-time?
   (I'm new to python and am coding with sublime text 3 in Linux Ubuntu)
3. Is there any more efficient way of writing the code?

Comment: Do you have the challenge source/link?

Comment: @Ludisposed Yeah, [here](https://quera.ir/problemset/university/287) it is. But it's in Persian. In fact it's not a challenge. This is an Iranian website to practice programming and this question was a homework passed to students of Sharif University of Iran 3  years ago in fall 2015. Now the question is for the people  to practice.

Comment: I struggled with the terminology a bit.  I think it's a little more conventional in English to call _x_ the **root** of _D(x)_, in case that helps anyone else reading this.  Otherwise, great question, and welcome to Code Review!

Answer (score 7):

## PEP-8

Try to stick to `PEP-8`. So `snake_case` for variable and method names and a lot of other guidelines. Check any other Code Review Python post for tips from people who can explain this better than me.

## Memory

Since you have 128MB of memory available, and a list of 1000 integers (`l = list(range(1000)); sys.getsizeof(l) + sum(map(sys.getsizeof, l))`) takes only 37kb on my system, I would not worry about clearing intermediate results.

## Pre-calculate the primes to 1000

If the input number never goes beyond 1000, pre-calculating all the primes will be the fastest and most efficient. Here is method `rwh_primes` from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068548/1562285) adapted for Python 3:

```
def primes(n):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python/3035188#3035188
    """ Returns  a list of primes < n """
    sieve = [True] * n
    for i in range(3, int(n ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[i * i :: 2 * i] = [False] * ((n - i * i - 1) // (2 * i) + 1)
    return [2] + [i for i in range(3, n, 2) if sieve[i]]
```

This takes about 50µs on my PC.

## `prime_factors`

You do some of unnecessary calls to `set` and `list`. I would implement this as a generator, and store it further upstream as a set:

```
def prime_factors(n):
    for factor in PRIMES:
        if factor > n**.5:
            yield n
            return
        while not (n % factor): # n is divisible by factor
            yield factor
            n //= factor
            if n == 1:
                return
```

## `sum_digits`

This one looks okay. You could use [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#divmod), but that is a matter of taste.

## `offspring`

No need for the intermediate `DX`:

```
def offspring(x):
    return x + sum(set(prime_factors(x))) + sum_digits(x)
```

## Main guard

Keep the main logic behind a `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard.

## eval

Instead of using `eval`, since you know it will be `int`, better use `int()`. `eval` can be dangerous, since it can execute arbitrary code. If you need to interpret a python literal, use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Then you do something very inefficient by creating a dict, then take only the values, apply `list`, `set` and `list` again. Easiest would be to just use a set-comprehension:

```
all_offspring = {offspring(i) for i in range(1, 1001)}
```

This will include some numbers over 1000, but this extra memory should be negligible.

## Test

You can spoof `input` on your system by something like

```
test_case = '''2
4
20'''
input = iter(test_case.split('\n')).__next__
```

## `main`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    PRIMES = primes(1000)
    all_offspring = {offspring(i) for i in range(1, 1001)}
    t = int(input())
    for i in range(t):
        n = int(input())
        if n in all_offspring:
            print('YES')
        else:
            print('NO')
```

## Timing

To time it you can use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module. There are enough posts on SO about this, and for [memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/552744).